# How to get a response from any URL?

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, ksh

I have been asked to write a shell script *To check if a URL is UP/Working or not for my Project.*

I tried to find some hints over the internet, but whatever I got is about checking whether the URL exists or not.

I first tried with `wget`.

```sh
wget -S --spider https://genesis-dev.webbank.ssmb.com:21589/gop-ui/app.jsp 2>&1 | awk '/^  /'
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then echo "Server is UP"
else
echo "Server is down"
fi
```

My next attempt was with `curl`.

```sh
curl -ivs  https://genesis-dev.webbank.ssmb.com:21589/opconsole-sit/opconsole.html#
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then echo "Server is UP"
else
echo "Server is down"
fi
```

But, both are checking existence of the URL not the response.

Comment: Just had a quick look at the curl man and it seems to suggest if you use --fail flag it will return an exit code of 22 rather than return a page saying about the problem, so only '200 OK' will give a return value of 0.

Answer (score 52):

`curl -Is http://www.yourURL.com | head -1` You can try this command to check any URL.Status code `200 OK` means that the request has succeeded and the URL is reachable.

You can also test URL availability and get the response code using `telnet` command

`telnet www.yourURL.com 80`

80 is the port number.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Tried this as well, but i think this is also checking the existence only. $ sh q.sh URL to check: http://www.google.com/akash http://www.google.com/akash exist
but this is giving error in browser ::404. That’s an error.

Comment: @Akash: Are you able to access that link through your browser?

Comment: if this is the link u r talking--www.google.com/akash--then NO--
It is givin me an error :: "404-not found"

Comment: Yeah,If that URL doesn't exists then it should:) What else are you expecting???

Comment: But- it is givivng me -- that it exist.. Below is the code :: $ vi q.sh #!/bin/ksh echo "give your url" read url curl -ls "&url" | head -1 if [ $? -eq 0 ] then echo "Exist" else echo "Doesn't Exist" fi When i run this :: $ sh q.sh give your url www.google.com/akash Exist
but it should go to ELSE..

Comment: @Akash: Yes that is correct. You are just checking for the exit status of the last command that is `curl -Is "&url" | head -1` and that command executed successfully.So,It is going to the `if` part not to `else`.

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "URL to check: " url
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
  printf '%s\n' "$url exist"
else
  printf '%s\n' "$url does not exist"
fi
```

The `if` statements are not necessary though, I put them here just to illustrate the flow of the script. [image]

Comment: i tried this and It is not giving me expected results.

Comment: $ sh q.sh 
URL to check: www.google.com
%s\n www.google.com does not exist

Comment: @Akash  See the updated answer. Don't put an extension to your script. Also run it just by `./checkURL`. Hope it helps

Comment: Need it for Project-Purpose.. think- don't have access to run it like that.. :(

Comment: What is `%s\n`  you put there? on your comment? Project-Purpose? You should be more specific of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This works as long as request is successful. In case of HTTP Error 401, I found it not working. I tested it to check my router 192.168.1.1, and it said "192.168.1.1" does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Following thing worked for me....

```
status="$(curl -Is http://www.google.com | head -1)"
validate=( $status )
if [ ${validate[-2]} == "200" ]; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "NOT RESPONDING"
fi
```

I tried from what @THUSHI wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you `ping` the URL, that will give you a response as well

```
ping -c 5 www.google.com
```

Where `-c` will count until the timeout of 5 expires.

In light of what I have been advised, `nmap` may work if you have it's package installed on your system. `curl` would be a better option, but nontheless here is an example using `nmap`:

`nmap -p 80 -sT www.google.com`

Comment: `ping` sends an `ICMP` message and definitely doesn't use port `80` or `443`. Also some servers block ping requests which still makes the attempt unreliable.

Comment: You can ping ports as well. I will submit an example of pinging a port on a website using nmap

Comment: nmap -p 80 -sT www.google.com will ping port 80. I will edit my answer shortly when i get access to my PC

Comment: `nmap` again is a non default package in many *nix systems. `curl` is more common shipped with the base system. You'd still need to install `nmap` to achieve something which can be achieved with standard *nix tools.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the info. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times curl does not work on https if you want to check you can check through **"curl --version"** you will not see the option https in that case you can use below

`wget --post-data '{"name":"Radha", "Car": "Jaquar"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --no-check-certificate https://yourrequiredURI`

Answer (score -2):

```
status="curl \"${server}:${port}\""  >/tmp/tmp.txt
host_check='grep "<html" /tmp/tmp.txt'
```